# Jquery show the latest data immediately when update of mysql table data

Tags: php, jquery, mysql

I have an table call `user`. Below is data:

```
+----------+----------+
| ID       | money    |            
+----------+----------+
| 1        | 100      |
| 2        | 200      |
+---------------------+
```

My `t.php` code is like below:

```
//above is connect to db, so I ignore to paste here.
$queryUser = DB::query("SELECT * FROM ".DB::table('user')." WHERE uid = '1'");
while($rowUser = DB::fetch($queryUser)) {
    $moneyN = $rowUser['money'];
}
if($_GET['act'] == 'add'){
    $moneyadd = $moneyN + 10;
    DB::query("UPDATE ".DB::table('user')." SET money = '$money' WHERE uid = '1'");
}
```

My `t.html` coding:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;">
<title>Testing</title>
</head>
<body>
<?php echo $moneyN; ?><br/><a href="t.php?act=add">Go</a>
</body>
</html>
```

How I just using jquery update the database, and show the latest data in `<?php echo $moneyN; ?>` without refresh webpage? I have find some tutorial on google, but cant work.

Comment: Use `AJAX` http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/ajax_ajax.asp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well this is what I use, it's not necessarily the best but whatever.
First of all replace `<?php echo $moneyN; ?>` with `<div id="something"><?php echo $moneyN; ?></div>`

Then add this to your `<head>`

```
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;">
<title>Testing</title>
<script>
    function reloadBalance()
    {
        $("#something").load("balance.php");
    }
</script>
</head>
```

This will load whatever `balance.php` prints into that div where the money is shown when `reloadBalance()` is fired. Now you might need to write such a script that only displays the money and nothing else.

To fire the event with a button or a link, just add an `onclick` event to it such as

```
<a href="#" onclick="reloadBalance()">Button</a>
```

Edit:: note that this requires jQuery so you'll have to include that for it to work.

Comment: is it every 3 second will reload the balance.php? if I just want when user click on the link then only reload balance.php? is it possible? thank you.

Comment: @SweeHong yeah, that's even easier. I'll update post in a sec